# Why is this marked as a potential leak using ARC?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, static-analysis

I'm still a bit confused with ARC, bridging, and certain non-toll-free bridged CF objects. My current confusion is around CFSocket. I'm pretty sure I'm cleaning up correctly, but the analysis tool is telling me otherwise. Maybe my dissonance is keeping me from seeing the leak, or the tool is wrong. I'm not ready to blame the tool, so I'm looking for other eyes to point out the issue. For example, am I missing a form of `__bridge` to transfer ownership to me?

In my project, using ARC, I have a TCP-based server. Let's call this class "MyServer". In MyServer, I have an internal property, socket, defined as such:

```
@property (assign) CFSocketRef socket;
```

This property holds the socket reference while the server is running. Stopping the server will release the reference, as will deleting the server object. I am also trying to clean up any potential leaks that get created during the process of starting the server. It is in this area where I'm having an issue with the static analysis.

The server is started with this method:

```
- (BOOL)startServer
{
    BOOL started = NO;

    NSLog(@"[%@ %@] starting server on port %u", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),self.port);

    self.lastError = nil;

    if ([self createSocket]) {
        started = YES;
        _state = SERVER_STATE_STARTING;
    };

    return started;
}
```

The `createSocket` method creates a socket (duh), like so:

```
-(BOOL)createSocket
{
    BOOL result = YES;

    self.socket = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,
                                 IPPROTO_TCP, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (self.socket != NULL) {
        int reuse = true;
        int fileDescriptor = CFSocketGetNative(self.socket);
        if (setsockopt(fileDescriptor, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
                       (void *)&reuse, sizeof(int)) == 0) {

            struct sockaddr_in address;
            memset(&address, 0, sizeof(address));
            address.sin_len = sizeof(address);
            address.sin_family = AF_INET;
            address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
            address.sin_port = htons(self.port);


            CFDataRef addressData = CFDataCreate(NULL,
                                                 (const UInt8 *)&address,
                                                 sizeof(address));

            if (addressData && CFSocketSetAddress(self.socket, addressData) == kCFSocketSuccess) {
                self.listenHandle = [[NSFileHandle alloc] initWithFileDescriptor:fileDescriptor
                                                                  closeOnDealloc:YES];

                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                         selector:@selector(receiveIncomingConnectionNotification:)
                                                             name:NSFileHandleConnectionAcceptedNotification
                                                           object:nil];
                [self.listenHandle acceptConnectionInBackgroundAndNotify];

                _state = SERVER_STATE_RUNNING;
            } else {
                result = NO;
                [self errorWithName:@"Unable to bind socket to address."];
            }
            CFRelease(addressData);
        } else {
            [self errorWithName:@"Unable to set socket options."];
            CFRelease(self.socket);
            CFSocketInvalidate(self.socket);
            CFRelease(self.socket);
            self.socket = nil;
            result = NO;
        }
    } else {
        [self errorWithName:@"Unable to create socket."];
        // CFRelease(self.socket); //NO - CFRelease(NULL) is a runtime error!
        result = NO;
    }

    return result;
}
```

When I run static analysis on this code, Xcode reports a bunch of potential leaks around self.socket. Here's one example, from the above `createSocket` method:

[image: (static analysis error)]

It is indeed true that I don't reference the object any more in this path. Perhaps there's some way to tell the system that I want to own the object and the reason it's complaining is that it can't tell that I do. Am I supposed to be using one of the `__bridge` casts to convey that information? I tried making the property retain or strong, but that doesn't build because it's not an object. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I noticed a few other execution paths where we were not cleaning up properly, so I've tweaked the logic accordingly to make doubly sure we clean up properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using a property, which is confusing the compiler. (It can't figure out that the call `self.socket = ...`, which is actually `[self setSocket:...]` expects an already-retained item and stores it.

If you use an instance variable directly, it should quiet the warning, because it will understand that you're holding on to a reference to that CFSocketRef on your own. (In this case, since your property is private and assign, you might as well use an instance variable anyway.)

Also, you're using the socket after you call CFRelease later on (you're calling CFSocketInvalidate on it after CFRelease), which is a bad idea.

Comment: +1 I'm a creature of habit. Among my habits are these two: I eschew instance variables and use properties exclusively instead, and I tend to use the property methods via the `self.` construct as much as is practicable.  Because socket is a very simple "store me" kind of property with no external access and doesn't have any "interesting" associated behavior, I think I'm going to change it into an ivar and just use it directly as you recommend. I'll also verify the ordering of any invalidate and release operations to make sure those are sane.

Comment: I'm making this one the answer because it most directly answers my question. Nonetheless, I think both this answer and Rob's answer are both valuable, but I had to choose no more than one to get the checkmark.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of thoughts:

1. The problem, as Jesse points out, is that you're using the accessor methods for `socket` and the analyzer is getting a little confused, thinking that the object passed to the `setSocket` method is leaking, not realizing that you're saving it in the instance variable. If you replace these occurrences of `self.socket` with `_socket`, your warnings related to `self.socket` go away.
2. Your code generates a second warning about `addressData` relate to the fact that you have an execution path whereby `addressData` could be `NULL`, but you're still calling `CFRelease`. You should make the code explicitly check for not `NULL` before trying to `CFRelease`.
3. You're releasing your socket twice, once before invalidating it, and again after. Clearly, you don't want to be releasing that twice. I'd also suggest setting the socket to `NULL`, not `nil`, not that it is that important.
4. Partially because of my change related to point #2 (where I'd otherwise need to add another `else` clause if `addressData` was `NULL`), but also as a general shift in logic, since you have many execution paths associated with failure, but only have one associated with success, I'd suggest to defaulting `result` to `NO` and set it to `YES` in that single successful execution path. This makes sure that we invalidate and release the socket in all of the different paths where the creation succeeded, but the listening didn't succeed. I believe there were a few execution paths that were not being covered properly, previously.

Thus, I end up with this rendition of `createSocket`:

```
-(BOOL)createSocket
{
    BOOL result = NO;

    _socket = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,
                                 IPPROTO_TCP, 0, NULL, NULL);

    if (_socket != NULL) {
        int reuse = true;
        int fileDescriptor = CFSocketGetNative(self.socket);
        if (setsockopt(fileDescriptor, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
                       (void *)&reuse, sizeof(int)) == 0) {

            struct sockaddr_in address;
            memset(&address, 0, sizeof(address));
            address.sin_len = sizeof(address);
            address.sin_family = AF_INET;
            address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
            address.sin_port = htons(self.port);


            CFDataRef addressData = CFDataCreate(NULL,
                                                 (const UInt8 *)&address,
                                                 sizeof(address));

            if (addressData) {
                if (CFSocketSetAddress(_socket, addressData) == kCFSocketSuccess) {
                    self.listenHandle = [[NSFileHandle alloc] initWithFileDescriptor:fileDescriptor
                                                                      closeOnDealloc:YES];

                    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                             selector:@selector(receiveIncomingConnectionNotification:)
                                                                 name:NSFileHandleConnectionAcceptedNotification
                                                               object:nil];
                    [self.listenHandle acceptConnectionInBackgroundAndNotify];

                    result = YES;
                    _state = SERVER_STATE_RUNNING;
                } else {
                    [self errorWithName:@"Unable to bind socket to address."];
                }
                CFRelease(addressData);
            }
        }

        if (result != YES) {
            [self errorWithName:@"Unable to set socket options."];
            CFSocketInvalidate(_socket);
            CFRelease(_socket);
            _socket = NULL;
        }
    } else {
        [self errorWithName:@"Unable to create socket."];
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

My original answer was focusing on the basics of Core Foundation Memory Management, while important, are not immediately relevant to the issue at hand.

**Original Answer:**

Yes, if a Core Foundation function call has `Create` or `Copy` in the name, you own the object. As such, you must either:

- Release the object via `CFRelease`. See [Core Foundation Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html).
- Transfer ownership to ARC via `CFBridgingRelease` or `__bridge_transfer`. See the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW1).

Clearly, the former is applicable here, but in general either approach works.

Comment: I don't think he wants to CFRelease it here; he wants it to stay around in self.socket.

Comment: @JesseRusak Quite right. I was too quick with the standard core foundation memory management advice. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Previously, it was cleaning up the created socket only if `setsockopt` failed. It now cleans up also if `addressData` creation failed or if `CFSocketSetAddress` failed, too.

Answer (score 1):

It's being reported as a potential leak because it is a potential leak. If the `createSocket` method is called twice, you have a leak because you never release the socket.

Try adding:

```
CFRelease(self.socket);
```

just before the call to `CFSocketCreate`. And made sure you are calling `CFRelease` on the socket in the `dealloc` method.

Comment: I don't think that's something that the analyzer can infer.

Comment: But that is a potential leak, yeah.

Comment: This is a fair comment - if startServer gets called while the server is already running, it should check to see if it's actually running and if a socket already exists. As for whether the analyzer can infer this kind of behavior, I'm not so concerned about that - I'm quite a bit more concerned about the leak, so thanks. +1.